# Combination of override and virtual in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to use the C++11 `override` specifier and noticed that it can be used together with `virtual`. Does this make a difference? Consider the following classes:

```
class Base
{
    virtual void fct() = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
    void fct() override {}
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
    virtual void fct() override {}
};
```

Is there a technical difference between `Derived1` and `Derived2`?

Comment: Same thing, the `virtual` in `Derived2` has no effect because `Base` already made that function `virtual`.

Comment: no difference at all. Using `override` can force the compiler to check if a function keeps virtual and override well.

Answer (score 4):

`override` is *always* used together with `virtual`. It is used to mandate that your virtual function overrides a virtual function in the base class.

An older rule means that, if it *does* override a virtual function in the base class, it's virtual automatically so you can skip writing the `virtual` out in your code. But "conceptually" the `virtual` is there already anyway.

So, writing `virtual` there will make no difference at all. Since you wrote `override`, the function *must* override a base class function (and, by extension, it must be virtual), otherwise your code won't compile.